# Unresolved external symbol error in c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to do a simple hw problem involving namespace, static data members and functions.  I am getting an unresolved external symbol error

```
Error   1   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static double JWong::SavingsAccount::annualInterestRate" (?annualInterestRate@SavingsAccount@JWong@@0NA)    SavingsAccount.obj  SavingsAccount
```

And I don't see why I am getting this error.  Maybe I don't know something about static variables compared to regular data members that is causing this error.  Here is my code:

SavingsAccount.h file

```
#ifndef JWONG_SAVINGSACCOUNT_H
#define JWONG_SAVINGSACCOUNT_H

namespace JWong
{
    class SavingsAccount
    {
    public: 
        // default constructor
        SavingsAccount();
        // constructor
        SavingsAccount(double savingsBalance);

        double getSavingsBalance();
        void setSavingsBalance(double savingsBalance);
        double calculateMonthlyInterest();

        // static functions
        static void modifyInterestRate(double newInterestRate);
        static double getAnnualInterestRest();
    private:
        double savingsBalance;

        // static members
        static double annualInterestRate; 
    };
}

#endif
```

SavingsAccount.cpp file

```
#include <iostream>
#include "SavingsAccount.h"

// default constructor, set savingsBalance to 0
JWong::SavingsAccount::SavingsAccount() : savingsBalance(0)
{}

// constructor
JWong::SavingsAccount::SavingsAccount(double savingsBalance) : savingsBalance(savingsBalance)
{}

double JWong::SavingsAccount::getSavingsBalance()
{
    return savingsBalance;
}

void JWong::SavingsAccount::setSavingsBalance(double savingsBalance)
{
    this->savingsBalance = savingsBalance;
}

// returns monthly interest and sets savingsBalance to new amount
double JWong::SavingsAccount::calculateMonthlyInterest()
{
    double monthlyInterest = savingsBalance * SavingsAccount::annualInterestRate / 12; 
    setSavingsBalance(savingsBalance + monthlyInterest);
    return monthlyInterest; 
}

void JWong::SavingsAccount::modifyInterestRate(double newInterestRate)
{
    SavingsAccount::annualInterestRate = newInterestRate;
}

double JWong::SavingsAccount::getAnnualInterestRest()
{
    return SavingsAccount::annualInterestRate;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unresolved external symbol on static class members](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195207/unresolved-external-symbol-on-static-class-members)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm presuming you are actually compiling the .cpp file (because the other functions link).

The error is likely due to not defining the `annualInterestRate` static variable.

You have declared it (in the class header), but it's not defined.  In your cpp file add:

```
// static member definition
double JWang::SavingsAccount::annualInterestRate = ...;
```

See an article highlighting the difference between [declaration and definition](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc/language/ref/cplr038.htm) of static members.

Section 9.4.2 of the C++ Standard says "The definition for a static data member shall appear in a namespace scope enclosing the member’s class definition."

Answer (score 4):

you need a line in your cpp file

```
double JWong::SavingsAccount::annualInterestRate = 0.7;  // or whatever you like
```

Comment: I thought static members got initialized to 0?  Or does that happen at a later time?

Comment: Either way, your program is not well formed until it has a definition.