# Unresolved external error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I've written this beauty:

```
#include <iostream>

struct something {
    static const char ref[];
};

const char something::ref[] = "";

template<int N, const char(&t_ref)[N], typename to> struct to_literal {
private:
    static to hidden[N];
public:
    to_literal() 
    : ref(hidden) {
        for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            hidden[i] = t_ref[i];
    }
    const to(&ref)[N];
};

template<int N, const char(&ref)[N], typename to> const to* make_literal() {
    return to_literal<N, ref, to>().ref;
}

int main() {
    const wchar_t* lit = make_literal<sizeof(something::ref), something::ref, wchar_t>();
}
```

It somewhat cleanly converts between string literal types. But when I compile it, MSVC says that the make_literal function is an undefined external function- which is clearly untrue as it's defined right there.

Edit: I've managed to reduce the problem down without all of the template gunk.

```
struct some {
    friend int main();
private:
    static wchar_t hidden[40];
public:
    some() 
    {    
    }
};

int main() {
    std::cout << some::hidden;
    //const wchar_t* lit = make_literal<sizeof(something::ref), something::ref, wchar_t>();
}
main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static wchar_t * some::hidden" (?hidden@some@@0PA_WA)
```

It's just a static array. Does life hate me?

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out what `const char(&ref)[N]` means. This code is either brilliant or insane

Comment: It's a reference to a string literal.

Comment: ".. this beauty" - A perfect example of the adage "Beauty is in the eye of the beholder" :)

Comment: Your reduced program is not a complete, compilable example.

Comment: @Alex: Forgive me, I forgot to include iostream.

Comment: I've added to your quick Connect bug report. ;).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unresolved external symbol on static class members](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195207/unresolved-external-symbol-on-static-class-members)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that is that `to_literal::hidden` is declared but never defined.  Take another look:

```
struct something {
    static const char ref[];  // declaration of something::ref
};

const char something::ref[] = "";  // definition of something::ref

template<int N, const char(&t_ref)[N], typename to> struct to_literal {
private:
    static to hidden[N];  // declaration of to_literal::hidden (but there's no
                          // definition anywhere)
public:
    to_literal() 
    : ref(hidden) {
        for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            hidden[i] = t_ref[i];
    }
    const to(&ref)[N];
};
```

To fix this, add a proper definition of `to_literal::hidden`:

```
template<int N, const char(&t_ref)[N], typename to>
to to_literal<N, t_ref, to>::hidden[N];  // definition of to_literal::hidden
```

Comment: I don't believe that it's unsafe, as the shared member is only ever copied from the template argument. Even if you created multiple to_literal instances from different threads, they're just going to assign it the same value. It doesn't matter which thread goes first or what view of what memory which threads have- because the value is the same on all of them. Also, for some reason, MSVC10 rejects that definition, it says that the template arguments are out of order.

Comment: @DeadMG: Oops, you're right about the multithreading part after thinking about it more.  I was thinking about what would happen if you called `make_literal` from multiple threads with different arguments, but if they have different arguments, then they'll refer to different template instances, so all is good.  If the arguments are the same, there's a race, but it doesn't matter who wins.  No idea why MSVC10 rejects this; g++ doesn't give anything even with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`.

Comment: I can't work out why MSVC10 rejects this either. I checked that specific error on MSDN and I most definitely did not make that mistake.

Comment: Yes, it looks like a bug in VC. If you change the reference to a pointer, it will work. I.e. `const char (*t_ref)[N]`, and other necessary adjustments.

Answer (score 2):

You're declaring but not defining the static member.  Add something like...

```
template<int N, const char(&t_ref)[N], typename to>
to to_literal<N, t_ref, to>::hidden[N];
```

I tried to check in MSVC for you too, but with VS2005 I get another stupid error...

```
template<int N, const char(&t_ref)[N], typename to> 
to to_literal<N, t_ref, to>::hidden[N];
```

...compiler complains of...

```
error C3860: template argument list following class template name must list parameters in the order used in template parameter list
```

Looks like when they fix one bug, there's another one behind it ;-/.

Comment: I've just tried that. Apparently, the class template argument list is mis-formed (and I remembered to add the array specifier on).

Comment: That can't work--you need to define the static member for the particular template instantiation you're talking about.  Remember, a template doesn't actually create anything, it only defines a way for creating something.

Comment: @Drew Hall: I'm defining it for all instantiations that may care to exist, just as if I defined a member function within the class, I'd expect that it would be instantiated for all instantiations unless I specialized the template.

Comment: @DeadMG: I've cut-and-pasted your code and added the code above (array dim added - thanks), changed your literal to something, and outputted the result - all works fine with GCC 3.4.6. @Drew: templates are instantiated when they're used.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I checked the MSDN page for this error and I definitely did not do that.

Answer (score 2):

When you define static members, a declaration does not suffice. [You must provide a definition outside the class](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/12581). I.e. add

```
wchar_t some::hidden[40];
```

outside the class, and it'll be defined.

Otherwise, if C++ allowed this, it'd cause the same problem as defining a global variable in a header -- every .cpp file that includes it will come with a duplicate definition, and at link time you'd get a multiply-defined symbol error.

Answer (score 1):

When I built this with VC 2008, that wasn't the error I got. The error was:

> Error 1   error LNK2001: unresolved
>   external symbol "private: static
>   wchar_t * to_literal<1,&public: static
>   char const * const
>   something::ref,wchar_t>::hidden"
>   (?hidden@?$to_literal@$00$1?ref@something@@2QBDB_W@@0PA_WA)   main.obj    Enabler

Removing `static` from the `to hidden[N];` member resolved the issue.

Are you sure you got the error message correct?

Comment: @OJ: I misphrased the error message. I can't accept removing the static qualifier. It's just a static array, I don't understand what the issue is.

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear enough in what I said. Removing the static actually defines the instance of the `hidden` member (which really is what I should have said the problem was). Another option is to define it externally, which is what Adam recommended.