# unresolved external symbol althought it's already defined

Tags: c++, static

I've got the following error althought I have a public static member called `myMember` in `myClass` class!

> error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static float MyClass::myMember" (?myMember@MyClass@@2MA)

**Note** When I double click on the error it does not take me to any line in the code!

The code:

```
class MyClass
{
    public:
       static float myMember;
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: It does not take you to any line in the code because it is an error detected by the linker (LNK2001), not the compiler. By the time the linker sees what used to be your source code, there is nothing left that speaks of lines.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unresolved external symbol on static class members](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195207/unresolved-external-symbol-on-static-class-members)

Comment: pro tip: if it's unresolved, it's because it's _NOT_ already defined

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You only declare myMember, define it in the .cpp corresponding to your (presumed) .h containing the class:

```
float MyClass::myMember;
```

Comment: I don't have .h file :$, is it a problem ?

Comment: @Jack: No, in that case just add the definition *outside* the class.

Comment: @Erik: Sorry, I've did but it gave me that `MyClass` has no member `myMember` !

Comment: @Jack: *after* the class definition.

Comment: `float MyClass::myMember;` after the brace `};` of the class directly