# unresolved external symbol when accessing a static variable

Tags: c++, linker-errors

```
class CommandManager {

public:
    void sendText(std::string command);
    static bool CommandManager::started;

private:


    bool parseCommand(std::string commands);

    void changeSpeed(std::vector<std::string> vec);
    void help(std::vector<std::string> vec);
};
```

And here's the client code:

```
CommandManager::started = true;
```

Linking these two files together I get:

> 1>UAlbertaBotModule.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static bool CommandManager::started" (?started@CommandManager@@2_NA)
>
> 1>C:\Development\School\cmput350-uofabot\UAlbertaBot\vs2008\Release\UAlbertaBot.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Where did I go wrong here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unresolved external symbol on static class members](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195207/unresolved-external-symbol-on-static-class-members)

Comment: I looked at that question and the solution did not help me

Comment: @KenLi: Try as I said in my answer. And let me know if you still face problem.

Comment: @KenLi - the other question is about the *exact* same issue - you declared but did not define your static in your class.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You're doing that incorrectly.

```
class CommandManager {

public:
    void sendText(std::string command);
    static bool started; //NOT this -> bool CommandManager::started
    //...
};
```

then put the definition of static member in `.cpp` file as:

```
#include "CommandManager.h" //or whatever it is

bool CommandManager::started = true; //you must do this in .cpp file
```

Now you can *use* `CommandManager::started` in your client code.

Answer (score 4):

You should have inside your class:

```
class CommandManager {
 public:
  void sendText(std::string command);
  static bool started;
  //// etc
};
```

and outside your class, in a `*.cc` file (not in a `*.hh` header file), a definition like

```
bool CommandManager::started;
```

BTW, I believe you'll better make that `private`.

Answer (score 2):

Consider putting

```
bool CommandManager::started;
```

where you **define** other members.