# using static member variable of a class inside a method of this same class

Tags: c++, class, methods, static

if I have a *static member variable*  of a class A declared in the file Af.h 
and I want to use this variable inside a method "met" of this same class inside the file Af.cpp, how do I proceed?
here is my files

## Af.h

```
class A
{
  public:
    static std::vector <int> vec;
    void met();
//....
};
```

## Af.cpp

```
//...
void A::met()
{
// I will use here some int variable i
vec.push_back(i);
//...
}
```

Unfortunately,this code provides the following compiling error:

```
undefined reference to A::vec
```

Comment: That's not a compiler error. That's a linker error. You're missing the definition of `vec`.

Comment: Duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1563897, http://stackoverflow.com/q/195207

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define it in `Af.cpp`:

```
std::vector<int> A::vec;
```