# How to use an array within a class?

Tags: c++, arrays, qt

I'm currently designing some code on QT that is built across multiple source. I want to create an array in one source and be able to access it in another source.

Currently in my Header I have class

```
Array_Class : public QString
{
public:
    static QString Data_Array [2];
};
```

I don't think I need a constructor as I'm going to "populate" the array before I read it.

currently in my source.cpp I have

```
Array_Class::Data_Array[0]= "foo";
Array_Class::Data_Array[1]= "bar";
```

however this gives me the error message undefined reference to "Array_Class::Data_Array". What am I missing? thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix

Comment: also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195207/unresolved-external-symbol-on-static-class-members

Comment: Deriving from QString is probably not what you want to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So far, you have only *declared* your array:

```
Array_Class : public QString
{
public:
    static QString Data_Array [2]; // -> only a declaration!
};
```

In order to use it, you must now define it. To do this, you need to place somewhere in your `.cpp`:

```
QString Array_Class::Data_Array [2];
```