# unresolved external symbol error when define the class

Tags: c++

I could not understand why when declaration a static variable causes a external symbol error. Who can describe the differences between below cases?

1) OK

```
class TrainComposition
{
public:
    int wagons;
    ...
}
```

2) Error (unresolved external symbol)

```
class TrainComposition
{
public:
    static int wagons;
    ...
}
```

3) Error (unresolved external symbol)

```
class TrainComposition
{
 static int wagons; 
 public:
    ...
}
```

Comment: You should initialize that static variable in global scope

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unresolved external symbol on static class members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195207/unresolved-external-symbol-on-static-class-members)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2) and 3) are of course the same, the visibility does not change anything on the problem.

You declare your variable, but you don't define it. In other words, in your .cpp file you should add

```
int TrainComposition::wagons = 0;
```

This is most often not necessary for `static` members that are `const`, but sometimes even then.