# error using static variable unresolved external symbol / undefined reference

Tags: c++, class, static

I am using `static` variable. After referring to [Unresolved external symbol on static class members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195207/unresolved-external-symbol-on-static-class-members), I modified the program with `Abc::ct`

```
#include <iostream>

class Abc
{
private:
    static unsigned int ct;

public:
    void f1()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
            f2();
    }

    void f2() {
        Abc::ct = 0;
        if (Abc::ct == 0)
            std::cout << "Zero iteration\n";

        std::cout << Abc::ct << "\t";
        ++Abc::ct;
    }
};



int main()
{
    Abc obj;
    obj.f1();
}
```

but getting error as `error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static unsigned int Abc::ct"`  in MSVC or `undefined reference to Abc::ct` in g++. How can I define static variable in class `Abc`?

Comment: The `Abc::ct` must be defined outside your class, above `main`.

Comment: Any way to define `static` variable only in class? (without `const` of course)

Comment: From your sample, instance data seems more appropriated that static data BTW

Comment: @ewr3243 If C++17 or above is used then: `inline static unsigned int ct;`

Answer (score 0):

You declared your `static` variable, but you did not define and initialize it. Above `main()`, but outside of your class, add the following line:

```
unsigned int Abc::ct = 0;
```

or, if you are using `C++17`, you can change your:

```
static unsigned int ct;
```

to:

```
static inline unsigned int ct = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define it:

```
unsigned int Abc::ct = 0;
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/BKAEzF)

Comment: What do you mean? Where to define? What about `static`?