# unresolved external symbol when using unordered_map

Tags: c++, std, unordered-map

I'm trying to create a basic Python interpreter using cpp and I'm facing an unresolved external symbol problem with the container of the _variables: an unordered_map

here is the declaration:

```
private:
    static std::unordered_map<std::string, Type*> _variables;//type is a base class for all the types of variables
```

and here is the relevant code using the container:

```
bool Parser::makeAssignment(std::string str)
{
    char ch = '=';
    int count = 0;
    Type* newVar;
    for(int i = 0; (i = str.find(ch, i)) != std::string::npos; i++)
    {
        count++;
    }
    if (count != 1)
    {
        return false;
    }

    std::string::size_type pos = str.find('=');
    std::string varName = str.substr(0, pos);
    std::string varVal = str.substr(pos + 1, str.size());
    Helper::trim(varName);
    Helper::trim(varVal);
    if (!isLegalVarName(varName))
    {
        throw SyntaxException();
    }
    if (getType(varVal) != NULL)
    {
        newVar = getType(varVal);
    }
    else
    {
        throw SyntaxException();
    }//checks if the declaration written is valid

    auto it = _variables.find(varName);
    if (it != _variables.end())
    {
        it->second = newVar;
    }
    else
    {
        _variables.insert({ varName, newVar });
    }
    return true;
}

Type* Parser::getVariableValue(std::string str)
{
    auto it = _variables.find(str);
    if (it != _variables.end())
    {
        return it->second;
    }
    return NULL;
}

void Parser::cleanMemory()
{
    _variables.clear();
}
```

I would also appreciate an explanation for this problem in general (LNK2001) because I have encountered it several times before.

Comment: Add a definition in you cpp: `std::unordered_map<std::string, Type*> Parser::_variables;`

Comment: Or add `inline` in front of the member declaration in the header, if you can use c++17.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unresolved external symbol on static class members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195207/unresolved-external-symbol-on-static-class-members)

Comment: first option worked, thank you all so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue has to do with the difference between a **declaration** and a **definition**.

A **declaration** such as

```
class Parser {
...
    static std::unordered_map<std::string, Type*> _variables;
...
};
```

tells the compiler that a symbol `Parser::_variables` will be available with the given type.

All code modules (`.cpp` files) which use that symbol will include the header file with the declaration to make the symbol known to that module.

In one place (only), the symbol needs to be **defined**, i.e. instantiated such that it is actually present in the final binary. Hence one `.cpp` file should have a definition like this:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, Type*> Parser::_variables;
```

Building of a program is, put shortly, a two-step process: compilation and linking.

During compilation, the binary translation of each code module is generated except for unresolved "external" references to symbols (functions and variables) that are used (declared), but not defined in that module.

During the linking step, all the modules are put together and unresolved references in each module are resolved by pointing to the module where they are defined. If it turns out that there is a symbol which is used, but not defined anywhere, then that reference remains unresolved and the final binary cannot be generated. Thus, the linker reports the observed error "unresolved external symbol".

Comment: It actually should be there, tried it without and had some problems

Comment: @MR.potato35 "static" on the declaration means that this symbol exists on class-level (i.e. common to all objects of that class), but "static" on the definition means that the symbol should be internal to that code module and hides it from the linker.